# Adding new custom map using R and leafletR

Tags: r, leaflet

I am trying to use leafletR with a custom base map. It work for any of them but using this particular one:

http://basemap.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/USGSTopo/MapServer

It is not workinganyone has any tip? Thanks!

```
library(leafletR)
## Not run:
# duplicates osm base map
addBaseMap(
  name="myosm",
  title="Duplicated OpenStreetMap",
  url="http://basemap.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/USGSTopo/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}.png"
  )
map <- leaflet(base.map="myosm")
## End(Not run)
rstudio::viewer(map)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API for the site doesn't appear to use the ".png" extension on the tiles. This works for me

```
addBaseMap(
  name="myosm",
  title="Duplicated OpenStreetMap",
  url="http://basemap.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/USGSTopo/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}"
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `.png` extension from the `url` property and it works. See:

http://basemap.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/USGSTopo/MapServer/tile/0/0/0

http://basemap.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/USGSTopo/MapServer/tile/0/0/0.png